# react-select Doesn't allow search with asterisk(*) in search text

Tags: reactjs, react-select

When I am searching data with asterisk(*) character in it, ajax returns the result, but it wont displayed in the select list.

example:

I have search engine which search by starts_with, for partial search I need to add asterisk(*) in front of the string.

- Apple
- Pineapple
- Crusted Apple
- Bilberry
- Blackberry

If I search for `App` it return the following result

- Apple
- Crusted Apple

To get `Pineapple` to included in the list I need to add asterisk in front of apple like `*apple`

When I add asterisk(*) ajax call returns the result, but the result is not shown in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by overriding the `filterOptions` prop of `react-select` as suggested here - [Doesn't allow search with asterisk(*) in search text](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/1864#issuecomment-314154201) using pattern search.

```
filterOptions(options, filterValue, excludeOptions, props) {
    var _this = this;
    var patternSearch = false;

    if(filterValue.contains("*")) {
      filterValue = filterValue.replace(/[*]/g, "[a-zA-Z0-9]*");
        patternSearch = true;
    }

    if (props.ignoreCase) {
      filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    }

    if (excludeOptions) excludeOptions = excludeOptions.map(function (i) {
      return i[props.valueKey];
    });

    return options.filter(function (option) {
      if (excludeOptions && excludeOptions.indexOf(option[props.valueKey]) > -1) return false;
      if (props.filterOption) return props.filterOption.call(_this, option, filterValue);
      if (!filterValue) return true;
      var valueTest = String(option[props.valueKey]);
      var labelTest = String(option[props.labelKey]);

      if (props.ignoreCase) {
        if (props.matchProp !== 'label') valueTest = valueTest.toLowerCase();
        if (props.matchProp !== 'value') labelTest = labelTest.toLowerCase();
      }

      if (patternSearch) {
        return props.matchProp !== 'value' && labelTest.match(sfilterValue);
      }
      else {
        return props.matchPos === 'start' ? props.matchProp !== 'label' && valueTest.substr(0, filterValue.length) === filterValue || props.matchProp !== 'value' && labelTest.substr(0, filterValue.length) === filterValue : props.matchProp !== 'label' && valueTest.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0 || props.matchProp !== 'value' && labelTest.indexOf(filterValue) >= 0;
      }
  });
}
```